# Do i need to record an audio to call getMaxAmplitude()?

Tags: java, android, audio

The media recorder in android has a method

> getMaxAmplitude()

I am making an application which deals with the amplitudes of sound falling on mic of a smartphone; it has nothing to do with actual sound recording. 
The developer site says one can call getMaxAmplitude() after

> setAudioSource().

So do I really need to record an audio to call getMaxAmplitude()?

Answer (score 3):

The `AudioRecord` class needs to be recording sound for `getMaxAmplitude` to work, but you can throw away the bytes that you receive without saving them to a file or processing.